# Create multi-level lookup table with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lets pretend an api is returning the structure in `apiResult`, and I want to create a two-level index for looking up what comments a given author have made on a given article.

The lookup table for the authors, articles and comments it self is easy enough, but I struggle with the `CommentsByArticleAndAuthor`-lookup.

In the `mapped` structure, I'm showing how I'm making the lookup index for the three 'easy' parts, and also how I want the `CommentsByArticleAndAuthor` to look.

How can I go forward generating this index?

```js
var apiResult = {
  Authors: [
    {
      Id: "author-id-1",
      Name: "Author One"
    },
    {
      Id: "author-id-2",
      Name: "Author Two"
    }
  ],
  Articles: [
    {
      Id: "article-id-1",
      Title: "This Great Article"
    }
  ],
  Comments: [
    {
       Id: "comment-id-1",
       AuthorId: "author-id-1",
       ArticleId: "article-id-1",
       Comment: "that great, hu?" 
    },
    {
      Id: "comment-id-2",
      AuthorId: "author-id-2",
      ArticleId: "article-id-1",
      Comment: "yes, that great"
    }
  ]
}

var mapped = {
  Authors: _.keyBy(apiResult.Authors, 'Id'),
  Articles: _.keyBy(apiResult.Articles, 'Id'),
  Comments: _.keyBy(apiResult.Comments, 'Id'),
  CommentsByArticleAndAuthor: {
    "article-id-1": {
      "author-id-1": [ "comment-id-1" ],
      "author-id-2": [ "comment-id-2" ]
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and how should look like the result?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. The result should be as in the `mapped` object.

Comment: Is your performance requirement critical enough to transform (and in the case of `CommentsByArticleAndAuthor` duplicate) all the data? If not why not just a few functions that operate on the data and use `_.filter`

Comment: this should *not* duplication data. Only id's will be stored multiple places.

Comment: Unless you want to create the Arrays for every article or author, I'd consider a plain filter both, simpler and probably more performant, than working with your mapping: `var comments = apiResult.Comments.filter(c => c.AuthorId === author.Id && c.ArticleId === article.Id);`

Comment: Yes, it might be easier and more performant to not break up the data. After reading the [redux docs on normalized state shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) I wanted to try out working with such a shape, without adding things like [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to the blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the comments and build a hierarchical object strcture.

```js
var apiResult = { Authors: [{ Id: "author-id-1", Name: "Author One" }, { Id: "author-id-2", Name: "Author Two" }], Articles: [{ Id: "article-id-1", Title: "This Great Article" }], Comments: [{ Id: "comment-id-1", AuthorId: "author-id-1", ArticleId: "article-id-1", Comment: "that great, hu?" }, { Id: "comment-id-2", AuthorId: "author-id-2", ArticleId: "article-id-1", Comment: "yes, that great" }] },
    mapped = { CommentsByArticleAndAuthor: {} };

apiResult.Comments.forEach(function (o) {
    var ref = mapped.CommentsByArticleAndAuthor;

    ref[o.ArticleId] = ref[o.ArticleId] || {};
    ref[o.ArticleId][o.AuthorId] = ref[o.ArticleId][o.AuthorId] || [];
    ref[o.ArticleId][o.AuthorId].push(o.Id);
});

console.log(mapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a more dynamic approach, you could use an array for the hierarchy and an object for the default values.

```js
var apiResult = { Authors: [{ Id: "author-id-1", Name: "Author One" }, { Id: "author-id-2", Name: "Author Two" }], Articles: [{ Id: "article-id-1", Title: "This Great Article" }], Comments: [{ Id: "comment-id-1", AuthorId: "author-id-1", ArticleId: "article-id-1", Comment: "that great, hu?" }, { Id: "comment-id-2", AuthorId: "author-id-2", ArticleId: "article-id-1", Comment: "yes, that great" }] },
    mapped = { CommentsByArticleAndAuthor: {} };

apiResult.Comments.forEach(function (o) {
    ['ArticleId', 'AuthorId'].reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r[o[k]] = r[o[k]] || { AuthorId: [] }[k] || {};
    }, mapped.CommentsByArticleAndAuthor).push(o.Id);
});

console.log(mapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sometimes the simple is the best.
I had hoped for something more 'smoothie-doothie' among all the nice helpers in lodash..

Comment: your dynamic approach is starting to look quite 'smoothie-doothie' :-) There is a 'hardcoded' `AuthorId` in the middle there which I guess doesn't belong?

Comment: that is a special dafault value if the key is `AuthorId`, because all other (just one in this case) default values are just empty objects.

Comment: ok. I haven't got to play with the code yet, but my thought was that if I'm gonna use the same code to index another structure, that `AuthorId` identifier should be derived from the content of the input array instead, but I guess all will be clear as soon as I can return back to that part of the code and try out the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: it's a problem of the different storrage of AuthorId in an array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but when running the code snippet, I don't get article-id and author-id at all. I get `ArticleId` instead of `article-id-1` and `AuthorId` instead of `author-id-1`. I would expect a `o[k]` somewhere in the `reduce`, but there is non.

Comment: sorry, missed that.

Comment: Great!
I'm quite sure this will solve my task at hand. I'm also quite sure it can be tweaked into a even more generic `keyBy`-like method. Something like `_.keyBy(comments, ['ArticleId', 'AuthorId'])`. But I'll see to that later.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the `apiResult.Comments` into the desired result:

```js
CommentsByArticleAndAuthor: apiResult.Comments.reduce((result, comment) => Object.assign(result, {
  [comment.ArticleId]: Object.assign(result[comment.ArticleId] || {}, {
    [comment.AuthorId]: result[comment.ArticleId] && result[comment.ArticleId][comment.AuthorId]
      ? result[comment.ArticleId][comment.AuthorId].push(comment.Id)
      : [comment.Id]
  })
}), {})
```

Your example:

```js
var apiResult = {
  Authors: [
    {
      Id: "author-id-1",
      Name: "Author One"
    },
    {
      Id: "author-id-2",
      Name: "Author Two"
    }
  ],
  Articles: [
    {
      Id: "article-id-1",
      Title: "This Great Article"
    }
  ],
  Comments: [
    {
       Id: "comment-id-1",
       AuthorId: "author-id-1",
       ArticleId: "article-id-1",
       Comment: "that great, hu?" 
    },
    {
      Id: "comment-id-2",
      AuthorId: "author-id-2",
      ArticleId: "article-id-1",
      Comment: "yes, that great"
    }
  ]
}

var mapped = {
  
  CommentsByArticleAndAuthor: {
    "article-id-1": {
      "author-id-1": [ "comment-id-1" ],
      "author-id-2": [ "comment-id-2" ]
    }
  },
  CommentsByArticleAndAuthor: apiResult.Comments.reduce((result, comment) => Object.assign(result, {
    [comment.ArticleId]: Object.assign(result[comment.ArticleId] || {}, {
      [comment.AuthorId]: result[comment.ArticleId] && result[comment.ArticleId][comment.AuthorId]
        ? result[comment.ArticleId][comment.AuthorId].push(comment.Id)
        : [comment.Id]
    })
  }), {})
}

console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: maybe i look wrong, but do you use some lodash in your answer?

Comment: if vanilla javascript has the power, using lodash would be pointless. I hoped that lodash would have something like the `keyBy` that could return a nested structure, though, but I guess not...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ninas great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391820/11956) I came up with this generic solution:

```js
const apiResult = {
  Authors: [{ Id: "author-id-1", Name: "Author One" }, 
            { Id: "author-id-2", Name: "Author Two" }],
  Articles: [{ Id: "article-id-1", Title: "This Great Article" }],
  Comments: [{ Id: "comment-id-1", AuthorId: "author-id-1", ArticleId: "article-id-1", Comment: "that great, hu?" }, 
             { Id: "comment-id-2", AuthorId: "author-id-2", ArticleId: "article-id-1", Comment: "yes, that great" }]
};
const mapped = {};

const indexBy = function(collection, keys, map = (item) => item) {
  let result = {};

  collection.forEach((item) => {
    keys.reduce((r, k, idx) => {
      let value = _.get(item, k);
      if (idx === keys.length - 1)
        return r[value] = [...r[value] || [], map(item)];

      return r[value] = r[value] || {}
    }, result);
  });

  return result;
}

mapped.CommentsByArticlesAndAuthor = indexBy(apiResult.Comments, ['ArticleId', 'AuthorId'], (item) => item.Id);
mapped.CommentsByAuthorAndArticle = indexBy(apiResult.Comments, ['AuthorId', 'ArticleId'], (item) => item.Id);

console.log(mapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {  max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

It let me index on as many levels that I want, and it let me transform the item indexed, defaulting to just store the full item. It also utilize [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) from lodash to support nested key values, e.g. `Author.Id` instead of `AuthorId`.